# Lorentz transformation proof

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

For an occurence, we can choose coordinates ct and x (calculating both time and space in length) ct and x thereby take on the form of a two dimensional vector.

Show that the same coordinates in S' are given by a matrice equation where the transformation matrix takes the form

$$\gamma \left( \begin{smallmatrix}
1&-\beta \\ -\beta&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$$

Where $\beta=\frac{v}{c}$

Is this really as simple as replacing t' for ct' in the definition: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/3/e/e3ee37f49f0adb02bc81590cb697d4d0.png

It seems too simple?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that you’re expected to derive that formula yourself.

Comment: That's a convoluted way of asking that. Wouldn't it be easier to ask for a derivation of the lorentz transformation?

But am I right in that the only difference between

https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/3/e/e3ee37f49f0adb02bc81590cb697d4d0.png

And

https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/d/6/0d6f3185dd8047b094a17478eed58b22.png

Is the algebra of substituting ct for t?

Comment: After reading it a few times, it makes no sense why it would be asking me to derive this https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/3/e/e3ee37f49f0adb02bc81590cb697d4d0.png

It's obviously asking why, if ct is chosen instead of t, then the formula becomes the one I wrote in my post.